# Can Hubot send an HTML or other type of formatted message to Hipchat?

Tags: html, hubot, hipchat

Looking at the [Hubot documentation](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/scripting.md) there seems to be no way to send a formatted message to the Hipchat client from a Hubot script.

Does anyone know of a way to better present lines of text sent from Hubot?

[Version 1](https://www.hipchat.com/docs/api/method/rooms/message) of the Hipchat API (albeit deprecated) suggests that a `message_format` parameter can be used to specify an HTML message.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, according to [this article](https://www.ravikiranj.net/posts/2015/code/how-to-send-html-messages-to-hipchat-from-hubot/#setting-it-up)